Optimal multiplication of two 3D arrays having a variable dimension
I would like to multiply tensors R = {R_1, R_2, ..., R_M} and X = {X_1, X_2, ..., X_M} where R_i and X_i are 3×3 and 3×N_i matrices, respectively. How can I make maximum use of NumPy functionalities during the formation of the R_i × X_i arrays?
My MWE is the following:
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

M = 5
R = [np.random.rand(3, 3) for _ in range(M)]
X = []
for i in range(M):
    N_i = np.random.randint(1, 6)
    X_i = np.random.rand(3, N_i)
    X.append(X_i)
    
result = np.zeros((3, 0))
for i in range(M):
    R_i = R[i]
    X_i = X[i]
    result = np.hstack((result, np.dot(R_i, X_i)))

print(result)

Edit #1:
Thanks for everyone who helped me with his valuable comments.
Meanwhile I was thinking about the role of N_is in my real problem and came to the conclusion that the number of unique N_is is in fact small (1 to 5; 2 is the most common one, but 1 is also very frequent). In this case, would there be a more efficient solution to the treatment of multiplications?
Another aspect which would be important: in practice, I store a 3 × N matrix X, not the individual X_i blocks. The columns of X are not ordered w.r.t. the R list. Instead, I store only an index vector p which provides the correct ordering for the X columns.
In this case, an einsum version would be the following (in comparison with the "direct" multiplication):
import numpy as np

M = 30
N = 100

np.random.seed(0)
p = np.random.randint(M, size=N)
R = np.random.rand(M, 3, 3)
X = np.random.rand(3, N)

result_einsum = np.einsum('ijk,ki->ji', R[p], X)

result_direct = np.zeros((3, N))
for i in range(N):
    result_direct[:, i] = np.dot(R[p[i]], X[:, i])

print(np.allclose(result_einsum, result_direct))

Edit #2:
It seems that Numba helps quite a lot:
import numpy as np
import numba
from timeit import Timer

M = 30
N = 100

np.random.seed(0)
p = np.random.randint(M, size=N)
R = np.random.rand(M, 3, 3)
X = np.random.rand(3, N)

@numba.njit
def numba_direct(R, p, X, result_direct, N):
    for i in range(N):
        p_i = p[i]
        for j in range(3):
            res = 0.0
            for k in range(3):
                res += R[p_i, j, k] * X[k, i]
            result_direct[j, i] = res

result_direct = np.zeros((3, N))
numba_direct(R, p, X, result_direct, N)
result_einsum = np.einsum('ijk,ki->ji', R[p], X)
print(np.allclose(result_einsum, result_direct))

ntimes = 10000

einsum_timer = Timer(lambda: np.einsum('ijk,ki->ji', R[p], X))
einsum_time = einsum_timer.timeit(number=ntimes)

numba_direct_timer = Timer(lambda: numba_direct(R, p, X, result_direct, N))
numba_direct_time = numba_direct_timer.timeit(number=ntimes)

print(f'Einsum runtime: {einsum_time:.4f} seconds')
print(f'Numba direct runtime: {numba_direct_time:.4f} seconds')

The execution times are the following for the above code:
Einsum runtime: 0.0979 seconds
Numba direct runtime: 0.0129 seconds


I know I am neither @mozway nor @hpaulj (this is referring to @chrslg's comment), but indeed there seems to be a feasible solution with einsum:
np.einsum("ijk,ki->ji",
          np.repeat(R, [x.shape[1] for x in X], axis=0),
          np.hstack(X))

Here is the full code with which I tested:
import numpy as np
from timeit import Timer

np.random.seed(0)

L, M, timeit_n_times = 3, 5, 10_000
R = [np.random.rand(L, L) for _ in range(M)]
X = []
for i in range(M):
    N_i = np.random.randint(1, 6)
    X_i = np.random.rand(L, N_i)
    X.append(X_i)

def original(R, X):    
    result = np.zeros((L, 0))
    for i in range(M):
        R_i = R[i]
        X_i = X[i]
        result = np.hstack((result, np.dot(R_i, X_i)))
    return result

def list_stack(R, X):
    result = []
    for i in range(M):
        R_i = R[i]
        X_i = X[i]
        result.append(np.dot(R_i, X_i))
    return np.hstack(result)

def preallocate(R, X):
    result=np.empty((L, sum(x.shape[1] for x in X)))
    k=0
    for i in range(M):
        R_i = R[i]
        X_i = X[i]
        result[:, k:k+X_i.shape[1]] = np.dot(R_i, X_i)
        k += X_i.shape[1]
    return result

def with_einsum(R, X):
    return np.einsum("ijk,ki->ji",
                     np.repeat(R, [x.shape[1] for x in X], axis=0),
                     np.hstack(X))
    
assert np.allclose(original(R, X), list_stack(R, X))
assert np.allclose(original(R, X), preallocate(R, X))
assert np.allclose(original(R, X), with_einsum(R, X))

print("original", Timer(lambda: original(R, X)).timeit(timeit_n_times))
print("list_stack", Timer(lambda: list_stack(R, X)).timeit(timeit_n_times))
print("preallocate", Timer(lambda: preallocate(R, X)).timeit(timeit_n_times))
print("with_einsum", Timer(lambda: with_einsum(R, X)).timeit(timeit_n_times))

Some observations:

The calculation times of list_stack() and preallocate() are marginally different, but are always faster than original(), which is also what is suggested and implied in @chrslg's answer.
Whether or not with_einsum() is faster or slower than the others depends pretty much on the shape of the problem:

For small, but many L×L matrices (L==3 in the question), with_einsum() wins.Here are the results for L, M, timeit_n_times = 3, 500, 10_000:
original 19.07941191700229
list_stack 6.437358160997974
preallocate 7.638774587001535
with_einsum 3.6944152869982645


For large, but few L×L matrices, with_einsum() loses.Here are the results for L, M, timeit_n_times = 100, 5, 100_000:
original 6.661783802999707
list_stack 4.67112236200046
preallocate 4.94899292899936
with_einsum 28.233751856001618





I did not check the influence of the size and variation of N_i.
Update
Based on the update to the question and @chrslg's thoughts, I tried whether zero-padding would also be a viable way to go. Bottom line is: probably not (at least not for the given example).
Here is the new testing code:
from timeit import Timer
import numpy as np

M, N, timeit_n_times = 30, 100, 10_000

np.random.seed(0)
p = np.random.randint(M, size=N)
R = np.random.rand(M, 3, 3)
X = np.random.rand(3, N)

einsum = lambda: np.einsum('ijk,ki->ji', R[p], X)

def direct():
    res = np.zeros((3, N))
    for i in range(N):
        res[:, i] = np.dot(R[p[i]], X[:, i])
    return res

# Rearrange data for padding
max_count = np.max(np.unique(p, return_counts=True)[1])
counts = np.zeros(M, dtype=int)

X_padded = np.zeros((M, max_count, 3))
for i, idx in enumerate(p):
    X_padded[idx, counts[idx]] = X[:, i]
    counts[idx] += 1

padded = lambda: np.einsum('ijk,ilk->ilj', R, X_padded)
    
result_einsum = einsum()
result_direct = direct()
result_padded_raw = padded()

# Extract padding result (reverse steps of getting from X to X_padded)
result_padded = np.zeros((3, N))
counts = np.zeros(M, dtype=int)
for i, idx in enumerate(p):
    result_padded[:, i] = result_padded_raw[idx, counts[idx]]
    counts[idx] += 1

assert np.allclose(result_einsum, result_direct)
assert np.allclose(result_padded, result_direct)

print("einsum", Timer(einsum).timeit(timeit_n_times))
print("direct", Timer(direct).timeit(timeit_n_times))
print("padded", Timer(padded).timeit(timeit_n_times))

Here, we first rearrange the data into X_padded, which is M×max_count×3-shaped, where max_count is the maximum number of references to one of the indices in R from p. We iteratively fill up X_padded for each index, leaving unused space zero-filled. In the end, we can again use a version of einsum to calculate the result (padded = lambda: np.einsum('ijk,ilk->ilj', R, X_padded)). If we want to compare the result to the results of the other methods, then we need to rearrange it back again, basically inverting the steps of getting from X to X_padded.
Observations:

Memory-wise, we have:

Saved on the side of R, as we don't need to replicate the individual 3×3 matrices, any more.
Paid on the side of X, as we need zero-padding.


Speed-wise, we have lost a bit, it seems;here are the results for M, N, timeit_n_times = 30, 100, 100_000:
einsum 0.7587459350002064
direct 13.305958173999898
padded 1.502786388000004

Note that this does not even include the times for rearranging the data. So probably padding won't help here – at least not in the way that I tried.



Thanks, @simon, for your thorough tests and helpful explanations. In my instances, L = 3 is fixed (the R_i matrices are 3D rotations), while N_i and M vary (in fact, I have M clusters with objects N_1, N_2, ..., N_M which I want to rotate). With this constraint, it seems that for large M or N_i range, einsum performs better than list_stack, but when both parameters are small, list_stack is faster. I prefer the einsum version, because it is quite compact. Thanks again for your kind help.

@TobiR Thank you for your feedback. Regarding the compactness of the einsum version: It looks more compact than it is, though. What happens in np.repeat(R, [x.shape[1] for x in X], axis=0) is that each matrix in R is repeated as many times as there are columns in the corresponding matrix in X. This is wasting a huge amount of memory and time on redundant data (I assume). However, I also did not find a better solution due to the variable shapes in X (which is what @chrslg also discussed already). So maybe, there is still a better way to solve it.

So you are using a separate R for each column of the combined X arrays.

@hpaulj Exactly. I did not find a better way, due to the differing shapes in X. I also tried with a list of the (replicated) matrices of R rather than using np.repeat(), to get only duplicated references and not duplicated memory. This worked just as well, but was a bit slower. I did not store the speed test, though, and I did not monitor memory in any case.

Nice one (I must confess that when I got BA, and suggested to wait a bit before awarding it, I wasn't really expecting, because of the heterogeneity of the shapes, that my BA was really at risk :D). For N_i, I guess it is better if they are not too big neither, because of the repeat. But if they are big enough, those repeat could maybe be padded with 0 and replaced with some stride trick. It depends on how different are those N_i. Bottom line, the best way is to test with real data

@chrslg Thanks, and fully agree on your conclusion. To be honest, I also thought it was a bit early when OP awarded BA. (That is not to say that I think your solution wouldn't have been worth it, but awarding BA without alternatives and without waiting a bit was probably not ideal – probably, even at this point, it is still too early.) I also agree that padding would be worth a try, depending on the actual distribution of N_i.

Thanks for your comments and sorry for early marking the other answer as BA (I was posting regularly on SO concerning other topics, where I usually received only one answer).
I have edited my question a bit, also making some remarks on N_i in my practical application.

@TobiR Thanks for your feedback! Regarding your update/edit: at this point, I am running out of ideas, and I would assume that you cannot get much faster than with your einsum version (other than maybe trying speedups with something like Numba).

@TobiR I added code and an experiment with zero-padding. See section Update.

@simon Thanks for your update. I have tried Numba with a naive (Fortran-like) implementation, and it indeed helps much (see Edit #2 in my question). First, I stupidly measured the compilation time along with the repeated executions, but now the results are quite encouraging.

@TobiR Sounds good! You might probably want to turn this update into your accepted answer, actually :D

I don't think there is much more to do.
Depending on how the N_i are distributed, for example, if half of N_i are 5, and other half 10, it might help to have two X (one M×5 X for the 5 1st columns, and one (M/2)×5 X for the others). That is, generally speaking, to work column-wise rather than "X-wise"
Or, in some other cases, to fill X with 0s (for example, if N_i is 10000 for 99% of the i, and 9999 for the remaining %).
But, roughly, numpy is to handle homogeneous dimensions array.
One point tho: never ever use hstack stack vstack, append or things like that in a for loop. That is very slow. That implies reallocating a new array and copying all the content of the former array into the new one.
Either use plain simple python lists to accumulate the results. And do the stacking at the end only
res=[]
for i in range(M):
    R_i = R[i]
    X_i = X[i]
    res.append(np.dot(R_i, X_i))

np.hstack(res)

Or allocate in advance the the result numpy array, and store the result as you iterate.
result=np.empty((3,sum(x.shape[1] for x in X)))
k=0
for i in range(M):
    R_i = R[i]
    X_i = X[i]
    result[:,k:k+X_i.shape[1]]=np.dot(R_i,X_i)
    k+=X_i.shape[1]


Thanks for your answer. I was afraid that this was the case. And also thanks for your instructions about the "extension" operations. If there is no way to "vectorize" this procedure, then no need to save the blocks in my case, because I can overwrite X with R*X.

If I may, you should wait a bit to be sure mozway or hpaulj had a shot before concluding. It is really not usual at all that they see ways (for example some fancy einsum) when I think there isn't.
